# How do I get all the roles that a user has and store them as a string?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Basically I just want to know how do I store all of the roles that a user has as a string for later use in the code to display in a reply

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has a property named [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles). That would be what you're looking for.
Example:

```
var roles = member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | ')
```